# Javascript returns NaN for audio duration depending on request sequence

Tags: javascript, html, audio, duration

I'm very new to Javascript.  I haven't had much success finding an answer to my query.  Here's a description of the problem.

I create an audio element and set the source to an .m4a file.  The .m4a file is able to both load and play successfully.

I get strange results, however, when requesting the source audio duration.  The following javascript produces 'NaN' in Chrome:

```
  //Create audio element based on HTML audio id and modify controls accordingly
  var aud = document.getElementById("storyTime");
  aud.setAttribute("src",story.audioTitle);
  console.log("DEBUG: Audio Duration = " + aud.duration);  //Get 'NaN'
  console.log("DEBUG: Audio Source = " + aud.src);
  aud.controls = true;
```

I tried then inserting a button with an onclick callback in the HTML with a similar function.  This button executing the "same code" returns the correct audio duration.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="checkDuration()" type="button">Get audio length</button><br>
```

javascript:

```
//Check audio duration
function checkDuration() {
  var aud = document.getElementById("storyTime");
  console.log("DEBUG: Audio Duration: " + aud.duration);
}
```

I figure the issue is with timing of said request.  However, if I preface the duration request with loading events such as 'canplaythrough' I still get the 'NaN' response when using the inline code.

```
aud.addEventListener("canplaythrough", console.log("Audio duration = " + aud.duration));
```

I appreciate any tips on appropriately handing audio loading event sequence.

---

Thanks to Andy for the suggestions.  I was able to query reliable duration with the following code.

```
  //Create audio element based on HTML audio id and modify controls accordingly
  var aud = document.getElementById("storyTime");
  aud.setAttribute("src",story.audioTitle);
  aud.controls = true;
  aud.load();

  aud.onloadeddata = function(){
    var audDuration = aud.duration;
    console.log("aud.duration = " + audDuration);
    }
  }
```

The solution I believe is due to invoking the `load()` call before listening for `loadeddata`.

Without the `load()` call, the audio **does** eventually load, but the `loadeddata` event fires before, or asynchronous, to duration available (methinks).

---

I made a test function to check audio duration.  I try checking with two methods as follows:

```
//Check audio duration and disable controls if NaN
function checkDuration() {
  var aud = document.getElementById("storyTime");
  aud.addEventListener("loadeddata",console.log("DEBUG (loadeddata version): Audio Duration: " + aud.duration));

  aud.onloadeddata = function(){
    var audDuration = aud.duration;
    console.log("DEBUG (onloadeddata version): Audio Duration: " + audDuration);
  }
}
```

The results:

DEBUG (loadeddata version): Audio Duration: NaN
DEBUG (onloadeddata version): Audio Duration: 1601.991111

I'm not sure I understand the difference, or why there would be a difference.

Comment: *"I preface the duration request with loading events such as 'canplaythrough'"*. Can you show how you do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The event `loadeddata` should be your friend here:

```
aud.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
 console.log("Audio data loaded");
 console.log("Audio duration: " + this.duration);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Andy, I tried the `loadedevent` trigger for querying duration (per your example), but still wind up with 'NaN'.

Comment: The only reason why it is NaN would be if it's not loaded or if the stream couldn't be read... did you check your dev console (-> network) if the file was loaded properly (code 200)?

Comment: The file does load correctly.  It's interesting to watch the sequence of events if I replace the console.log with alerts, which _seem_ to have the effect of pacing things since they wait on my OK keypress.
The first event triggers the audio load, in my case text entry.  The `loadeddata` event occurs, and the first alert reports duration = 'NaN'.  Meanwhile, the audio controller has loaded on the page but sure enough shows 0.00!  I press OK on the alert and suddenly the audio controller updates to show the full loaded audio length. Subsequent audio duration queries report the correct duration.

Comment: And you said you tried "canplaythrough" .. hmm.. maybe you need to listen for "stalled" events which indicates that there are issues loading the data ..