# HTMLMediaElement.duration returning NaN for audio file

Tags: javascript, audio

I have the following JavaScript to play a sound when a button is clicked on the screen, however I'm only getting NaN for the duration.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function play_sound() {
    var audio = new Audio("assets/sound.ogg");
    audio.play();
    var duration = audio.duration;
    console.log(duration);
  }

  $(document).on("click", ".box", function(e) {
    play_sound();
  });
});
```

In my research I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019672/javascript-returns-nan-for-audio-duration-depending-on-request-sequence) which uses the "loadeddata" event, however I'm not sure how to incorporate that into my code. Should I use an `<audio>` element in my HTML?

Comment: Maybe it's because the audio isn't playing yet? Try putting it after the audio.play(); statement.

Comment: @Oliver Tried that, no luck unfortunately. Edited my question and put it after to show that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my shot at it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function play_sound() {
        var audio = new Audio("assets/sound.ogg");
        audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(_event) {
            var duration = audio.duration;
            console.log(duration);
        });

        audio.play();
    }

    $(document).on("click", ".box", function(e) {
        play_sound();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2pe6hcf/1/

Added the `eventListener` and it works perfectly.